# Grouping/Joining elements of an Array List together by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ramda.js

I have the following data structure as a input

I want to achieve a special grouping of the data, without loosing any data

```
const input =
[
  {
   Id: 10,
   name: "Test_10",
   points: [{…}, {…}, {…}],
   label: "Label_10",
   level: "1",
   unit: "%"
  },
  {
   Id: 20,
   name: "Test_10",
   points: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
   label: "Label_10",
   level: "1",
   unit: "%"
  },
  {
   Id: 30,
   name: "Test_10",
   points: [{…}, {…}, {…}],
   label: "Label_10",
   level: "2",
   unit: "°C"
  },
  {
   Id: 40,
   name: "Test_10",
   points: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
   label: "Label_10",
   level: "2",
   unit: "°C"
  }
]
```

After my conversion/grouping i want to have this output below. I want to combine all point information with in the same "level". So that i have on Level "1" seven points in my output. But i want it only for my Level 1 items, not for Level 2. Is there a easy way to achieve this? (Maybe, but necessary with functions out of ramda or rxjs?)

```
const output =
[
  {
   Id: 10, // is not important for further code, can be first entry
   name: "XX", // is not important for further code
   points: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}], // all points now together
   label: "Label_10",
   level: "1",
   unit: "%"
  },
  {
   Id: 30,
   name: "Test_10",
   points: [{…}, {…}, {…}],
   label: "Label_10",
   level: "2",
   unit: "°C"
  },
  {
   Id: 40,
   name: "Test_10",
   points: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
   label: "Label_10",
   level: "2",
   unit: "°C"
  }
]
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: i tried groupBy label - before joining merging the identical objects together, but this doesn't worked. I cant combine the data points together in my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I wasn't very happy with my original solution below.  This version does not include any dependencies and, if not crystal-clear, is a fairly straightforward ES6 solution:

```js
const combine = (a, b) =>
  ({...b, points: a .points .concat (b .points) })
 
const mergeLevel1Points = xs => 
  [xs .filter (x => x .level == '1') .reduce (combine, {points: []}), ...xs .filter(x => x .level != '1')]

 
const input = [
  {Id: 10, name: "Test_10", points: [1, 2, 3], label: "Label_10", level: "1", unit: "%"},
  {Id: 20, name: "Test_10", points: [4, 5, 6, 7], label: "Label_10", level: "1", unit: "%"},
  {Id: 30, name: "Test_10", points: [8, 9], label: "Label_10", level: "2", unit: "°C"},
  {Id: 40, name: "Test_10", points: [10, 11, 12], label: "Label_10", level: "2", unit: "°C"}
]
 
console .log (
  mergeLevel1Points (input)
)
```

It keeps the data from the last, rather than the first, `level 1` element.  I'm sure this could be changed fairly easily, but the question made it clear that it's not important, so I kept what fell out of the implementation.

---

### Original Solution

Here's a Ramda solution.  I don't find it particularly readable, but the requirements are themselves fairly odd, so perhaps that's ok:

```js
const combine = mergeWithKey (
  (key, a, b) => key == 'points' ? concat(a, b) : a
)

const mergeLevel1Points = pipe (
  partition (propEq ('level', '1') ),
  apply (useWith (prepend, [reduce (combine, {})] ))
)  

const input = [
  {Id: 10, name: "Test_10", points: [1, 2, 3], label: "Label_10", level: "1", unit: "%"},
  {Id: 20, name: "Test_10", points: [4, 5, 6, 7], label: "Label_10", level: "1", unit: "%"},
  {Id: 30, name: "Test_10", points: [8, 9], label: "Label_10", level: "2", unit: "°C"},
  {Id: 40, name: "Test_10", points: [10, 11, 12], label: "Label_10", level: "2", unit: "°C"}
]

console .log (
  mergeLevel1Points (input)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>
const {mergeWithKey, concat, pipe, partition, propEq, apply, useWith, prepend, reduce} = R
</script>
```

`combine` just takes two items and uses mostly the first one, combining its `points` with those of the second one.  It could also be written like this:

```js
const combine = (a, b) => ({...a, points: (a.points || []).concat(b.points)})
```

The main function first groups the input into those that match `level 1` and those that don't (`partition`).  Then it folds the first group into a single value using `combine` (`reduce(combine, {})`) and prepends the result to the second group.  The `apply` here just converts our function of two arguments into one that accepts an array *containing* those two arguments, to match the output from `partition`.

This version is slightly distasteful to me due to the use of `useWith`; it's a very powerful and often succinct function, but it often hurts readability.  (If I was to use it for a public function, and not, as used here, anonymously, then I would probably add an `identity` to it [`useWith (prepend, [reduce (combine, {}), identity] )`], so that the returned function properly reported its arity.  But that's a minor point.)

Still, it's not a horrible implementation, and it has the advantage of being concise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works for my special case. When i have more than 2 Levels, maybe a third level entry in input. What can i do, to only group Level 1 and 2 together and let level 3 unchanged? Here is my new input:

Comment: `const input = [
  {Id: 10, name: "Test_10", points: [1, 2, 3], label: "Label_10", level: "1", unit: "%"},
  {Id: 20, name: "Test_10", points: [4, 5, 6, 7], label: "Label_10", level: "1", unit: "%"},
  {Id: 30, name: "Test_10", points: [8, 9], label: "Label_10", level: "2", unit: "°C"},
  {Id: 40, name: "Test_10", points: [10, 11, 12], label: "Label_10", level: "2", unit: "°C"},
  {Id: 50, name: "Test_10", points: [13, 14, 15], label: "Label_10", level: "2", unit: "°C"},
  {Id: 60, name: "Test_10", points: [100, 200], label: "Label_10", level: "3", unit: "°C"}
]`

Comment: Your original solution is very good, maybe you can update both solutions, so that i can follow both strategies and understand it better. Thank you in advance,

Comment: Can i define something like: every level except for '3' in my pipe? Would be saver, because everything except 3 would be combined. And i don't have to know which new Level may appear in my input, i need just the information this level should not be grouped

Comment: @Maverick777: Please don't try to treat StackOverflow as a code-writing service. It's simply a Q & A site. However, that should be an easy change. Add a parameter to the main function that is a function from your item to `true` or `false` (i.e. a predicate), write a `not` function (`(fn) => (...args) => !fn(...args)`) and pass `myPredicate` and `not(myPredicate)` to the two `filter` invocations.  Then you can call things like `mergeGroupPoints (x => ['1', '2'].includes(x.level)) (input2)` or `mergeGroupPoints (x => x.level != '3') (input2)`. If you have trouble with this, open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = [
  {Id: 10, name: "Test_10", points: [1, 2, 3], label: "Label_10", level: "1", unit: "%"},
  {Id: 20, name: "Test_10", points: [4, 5, 6, 7], label: "Label_10", level: "1", unit: "%"},
  {Id: 30, name: "Test_10", points: [8, 9], label: "Label_10", level: "2", unit: "°C"},
  {Id: 40, name: "Test_10", points: [10, 11, 12], label: "Label_10", level: "2", unit: "°C"}
];

const mergeLevelOnePoint = R.pipe(
  R.partition (R.propEq('level', '1')),
  R.zipWith(
    R.call,
    [
      R.pipe(
        R.reduce
          (R.mergeDeepWithKey((key, left, right) => (
            key === 'points'
              ? R.concat(left, right)
              : right
          )))
          ({}),
        R.of,
      ),
      R.identity,
    ],
  ),
  R.unnest,
);

console.log(mergeLevelOnePoint(input));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

A more human-readable point-free solution in Ramda:

1. `R.partition` split the input into `[ levelOneEntries, otherLevelEntries ]`
2. Pipe partition output into `R.zipWith(R.call, [fn1, fn2])`, which does `[fn1(levelOneEntries), fn2(otherLevelEntries)]`. `fn1` deep-merges entries, concatenating `points`; while `fn2` is just a identity function.
3. The `R.zipWith` will outputs a `[[mergedLevelOneEntry], otherLevelEntries]`, which is a form of Array of Array. Therefore, use `R.unnest` to flatten into one array, i.e. `[mergedLevelOneEntry, otherLevelEntryA, otherLevelEntryB, ...]`

Comment: Thank you very much! See my coment on the answer over this one: "Can i define something like: every level except for '3' in my pipe? Would be saver, because everything except 3 would be combined. And i don't have to know which new Level may appear in my input, i need just the information this level should not be grouped"

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to do that.

```
function groupByLevel(level) {
  return input.reduce((arr, currentValue) => {

    if (currentValue.level === level) {
      const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.level === level);

      if (index === -1) {
        arr.push(currentValue);
      } else {
        arr[index].points = arr[index].points.concat(currentValue.points);
      }
    } else {
      arr.push(currentValue);
    }

    return arr;
  }, []);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
const input = [{
    Id: 10,
    name: "Test_10",
    points: [1, 2, 3],
    label: "Label_10",
    level: "1",
    unit: "%"
  },
  {
    Id: 20,
    name: "Test_10",
    points: [4, 5, 6, 7],
    label: "Label_10",
    level: "1",
    unit: "%"
  },
  {
    Id: 30,
    name: "Test_10",
    points: [1, 2, 3],
    label: "Label_10",
    level: "2",
    unit: "°C"
  },
  {
    Id: 40,
    name: "Test_10",
    points: [4, 5, 6, 7],
    label: "Label_10",
    level: "2",
    unit: "°C"
  }
]

function groupByLevel(level) {
  return input.reduce((arr, currentValue) => {

    if (currentValue.level === level) {
      const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.level === level);

      if (index === -1) {
        arr.push(currentValue);
      } else {
        arr[index].points = arr[index].points.concat(currentValue.points);
      }
    } else {
      arr.push(currentValue);
    }

    return arr;
  }, []);
}

console.log(groupByLevel("1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Grouping & Filter 
**Demo**:

```js
const input = [{
    Id: 10,
    name: "Test_10",
    points: [1, 2, 3],
    label: "Label_10",
    level: "1",
    unit: "%"
  },
  {
    Id: 20,
    name: "Test_10",
    points: [4, 5, 6, 7],
    label: "Label_10",
    level: "1",
    unit: "%"
  },
  {
    Id: 30,
    name: "Test_10",
    points: [1, 2, 3],
    label: "Label_10",
    level: "2",
    unit: "°C"
  },
  {
    Id: 40,
    name: "Test_10",
    points: [4, 5, 6, 7],
    label: "Label_10",
    level: "2",
    unit: "°C"
  }
]


let levelsGroups;

function filterElement(el){
   const topElement = levelsGroups[el.level]
   if(!topElement){
      levelsGroups[el.level] = el;
      return true;
   }
   topElement.points.concat(el.points);   
   return false;
}

function groupInput() {
    levelsGroups = {};
    return input.filter(filterElement);
}
console.log(groupInput());
```